# How do you manually place forms from a formset?

Tags: django

I have a template page where it's suppose to load a form from the formset if a database query returns FALSE.

```
    <form method="post" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for form in formset %}
        {% if comparelist.item2 %}
            <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item2.name}}</div>
            <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item2.price}}</div>
            <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item2.store}}</div>            
        {% else %}
        <div>
            {{form.form-0}}
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% if comparelist.item3 %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item3.name}}</div>
            <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item3.price}}</div>
            <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item3.store}}</div>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div>
            {{form.form-1}}
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% if comparelist.item4 %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item4.name}}</div>
            <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item4.price}}</div>
            <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item4.store}}</div>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div>
            {{form.form-2}}
        </div>
        {%endfor%}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

But obviously `{{form.form-x}}` doesn't work.
So how do I insert these forms in manually?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here. What is that syntax supposed to achieve? And what is `comparelist`?

Comment: It's simply a database query passed onto the template as context. eg if comparelist.item2 is True, then it would list the name, price, and store. If False, then it should display the form. Basically, if there's information to display, display it. If there's no information to display, display a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what the `{{form.form-2}}` syntax is supposed to do. But I think what you want is to simply refer to the forms directly via their position, just like you do with the comparelist items. So remove the for loop and do that:

```
<form method="post" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}

    {% if comparelist.item2 %}
        <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item2.name}}</div>
        <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item2.price}}</div>
        <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item2.store}}</div>            
    {% else %}
    <div>
        {{formset.forms.0}}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if comparelist.item3 %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item3.name}}</div>
        <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item3.price}}</div>
        <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item3.store}}</div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div>
        {{formset.forms.1}}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if comparelist.item4 %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item4.name}}</div>
        <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item4.price}}</div>
        <div class="col-3">{{comparelist.item4.store}}</div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div>
        {{formset.forms.2}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```